# NsError and userinfo

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am building an IOS SDK.

Basically, I am making an asynchronous network request (API Call). When there is an error, a dictionary is returned with keys "error_key", "error_description", "error_code".

How can I represent those three information using NSError?

I am doing the following:

```
 NSMutableDictionary* details = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[details setValue: error_description forKey: NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
[NSError errorWithDomain: APPErrorDomain code: error_code userInfo: details];
```

How do I change the userinfo to also take into account error_key?

Comment: well the new syntax is pretty nice for this: `NSDictionary* details = @{key1:value1,key2:value2};`

Comment: voting to close, because of a lack of effort in attempting to find the answer in the NSMutableDictionary doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`userInfo` is a simple dictionary that can have any keys and values that you put into it. So in your case it's just a matter of doing something like:

```
details[@"ErrorKey"] = error_key;
```

and then creating the NSError object with those user details.

Answer (score 9):

If your "error_key" corresponds to one of the predefined `userInfo` dictionary keys then you should add it to the `userInfo` dictionary using the proper key. The defined keys are:

```
NSString * const NSLocalizedDescriptionKey;
NSString * const NSErrorFailingURLStringKey;
NSString * const NSFilePathErrorKey;
NSString * const NSStringEncodingErrorKey;
NSString * const NSUnderlyingErrorKey;
NSString * const NSURLErrorKey;
NSString * const NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey;
NSString * const NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey;
NSString * const NSLocalizedRecoveryOptionsErrorKey;
NSString * const NSRecoveryAttempterErrorKey;
NSString * const NSHelpAnchorErrorKey;
NSString * const NSURLErrorFailingURLErrorKey;
NSString * const NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey;
NSString * const NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey;
```

If it is custom key, then you should just add it to your `userInfo` dictionary with whatever key you want.

Comment: better answer adds something to the context, but doesn' really answer the question of adding another kv pair

Comment: should I be using NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey for the error key and NSLocalizedDescriptionKey for the error description?